# Как отключить анимацию когда элемент невидим?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Есть индикатор загрузки, который постоянно крутится. Мне нужно отключать его анимацию, пока он невидим. Как это сделать? Желательно, чтобы это было без вмешательства кода.

**UPD**

Я нашел одно решение... Пока не буду его приводить. Но вот в чем вопрос. Работает ли оно? Как проверить, запущена ли анимация, если элемент невидим? :)

Comment: А что означает «невидим»? Visibility = Collapsed? Прикрыт сверху другими элементами?

Comment: @VladD, `Visibility == Collapsed || Visibility == Hidden`

Comment: @VladD, есть еще вопрос относящийся к теме. Обновил вопрос

Comment: А как у вас запускается анимация?

Comment: Проверить просто по идее: если вы анимируете какое-то значение, прочитайте его из code behind.

Comment: А зачем отключать? Его ж не видно? Наверняка WPF не будет его повторно пытаться отрисовывать, раз он невидимый. А анимация просто `double`-значения по идее не должна сильно грузить машину.

Comment: @VladD, в моем случае действительно незачем. Но по дефолту анимация изменяет значение 60 раз в секунду. В общем мониторинг производительности показывал что работу проца на 5-10%. Но в моем случае это само собой прошло когда я убавил фпс.

Comment: @VladD анимация запускается на Loading элемента который вращаю